# How to Show Images of mysql(longblob type field) in Movlet form view

Tags: movilizer

I have images stored in MySQL(**longblob** type field) table column. How to show this images in my movlet form view(type="5").

if Any reference, please share with me.

Thanks in Advance
Krish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the icon answer (attributeAnswer 12) or if you need the image bigger than that, you can create a complex with a image screen (question type 1)

Comment: Hi Inazense. thanks for your answer. I need thumbnail of image and once i click on it, will show large size image. is it possible with movilizer 2.6? or any other approach is available?

Comment: If I remember correctly, with the second approach (complex with image screen) when you press in the image you will see it in a larger size, from version 2.4 and above